# Unable to show page numbers on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to present a huge dataset through flask. Unfortunately, the page numbers under the table do not fall in same line, rather each page number is being displayed as unordered list. Please refer to the below screenshot for the issue.

[image: Broken page numbers]

The html of the page looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <table class='tableView'>
        <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th>{{ columnNames[0] }}</th>
                <th>{{ columnNames[1] }}</th>
                <th>{{ columnNames[2] }}</th>
                <th>{{ columnNames[3] }}</th>
                <th>{{ columnNames[4] }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='5'>
                    <div class='links'>
                        {{ pagination.links }}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            {% for record in records.values %}                
                <tr>
                    {% for index in range(5) %}
                        <td>{{ record[index] }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div>
{% endblock %}
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

table.tableView {
    border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
    background-color: #AEDBEE;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

table.tableView td, table.tableView th {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

table.tableView tbody td {
    font-size: 13px;
}

table.tableView tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #D0E4F5;
}

table.tableView thead {
    background: #1C6EA4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}

table.tableView thead th {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}

table.tableView thead th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table.tableView tfoot {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #43443B;
    background: #D0E4F5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
    border-top: 2px solid #313644;
}

table.tableView tfoot td {
    font-size: 14px;
}

table.tableView tfoot .links {
    text-align: center;
}

table.tableView tfoot .links a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #246688
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

How can I show the page numbers, so that they are on the same line just below the table?

Edit 1: The generated html structure is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FetchDataAPI</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="/static/css/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table class='tableView'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>                
                        <th>BATCH_ID</th>
                        <th>CHAR_ID</th>
                        <th>BATCH_TIME</th>
                        <th>CHAR_NAME</th>
                        <th>CHAR_VALUE</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='5'>
                    <div class='records'>
                        <ul class="pagination"><li class="previous disabled unavailable"><a> &laquo; </a></li><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=2">2</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=3">3</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=4">4</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=5">5</a></li><li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=51">51</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=52">52</a></li><li class="next"><a href="/ip21data?page=2">&raquo;</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>                    
                    <td>86709.0</td>                    
                    <td>7786.0</td>                    
                    <td>01-JAN-14 08:43:19.0</td>                    
                    <td>START</td>                    
                    <td>LR 8986</td>                    
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would like to know what's the dynamic data coming up inside that pagination.links . From what I see in the image it's an unordered list and that's the reason it's not in same line.

Comment: Do you absolutely want your pagination to be in the same table ? Can't you put it right under ?

Comment: It could also be under the table, it does not matter. All I would want is to line them up in the same row.

Comment: @fahad.kazi The whole dataset has been divided such that every page shows exactly 25 items. Corresponding to the number of items, there would be number of pages. Though it could be random based on the size of the dataset, but it would start from 1 and increment one at a time.

Comment: `.links li { display: inline-block }` try using this css

Comment: @Chilll007 it does not work!

Comment: Can you share a working link? it will be more understandable.

Comment: @PiyushVerma it would not be possible due to the company policies.

Comment: great if you post your generated html structure then we will get to know what is happening.

Comment: `.links li a{ display: inline-block }` please try this and see if its working or not?

Comment: @RishikMani If possible post generated html structure in image that will also help

Comment: Also check your css is rendering or not as per the image and your css, you write the css right, but not a single css applying on your html so maybe that is because of hierarchy or your css is not rendering.

Comment: Updated the html structure. @PiyushVerma I have verified by removing the CSS, it is being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table.tableView {
    border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
    background-color: #AEDBEE;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

table.tableView td, table.tableView th {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    padding: 3px 2px;
}

table.tableView tbody td {
    font-size: 13px;
}

table.tableView tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #D0E4F5;
}

table.tableView thead {
    background: #1C6EA4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}

table.tableView thead th {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}

table.tableView thead th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

table.tableView tfoot {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #43443B;
    background: #D0E4F5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcebf7 0%, #d4e6f6 66%, #D0E4F5 100%);
    border-top: 2px solid #313644;
}

table.tableView tfoot td {
    font-size: 14px;
}

table.tableView tfoot .records {
    text-align: center;
}
table.tableView tfoot .records ul{
  margin:0;
}
table.tableView tfoot .records li{
  display:inline-block;
}
table.tableView tfoot .records a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #246688;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <table class='tableView'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>                
                        <th>BATCH_ID</th>
                        <th>CHAR_ID</th>
                        <th>BATCH_TIME</th>
                        <th>CHAR_NAME</th>
                        <th>CHAR_VALUE</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='5'>
                    <div class='records'>
                        <ul class="pagination"><li class="previous disabled unavailable"><a> &laquo; </a></li><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=2">2</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=3">3</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=4">4</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=5">5</a></li><li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=51">51</a></li><li><a href="/ip21data?page=52">52</a></li><li class="next"><a href="/ip21data?page=2">&raquo;</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>                    
                    <td>86709.0</td>                    
                    <td>7786.0</td>                    
                    <td>01-JAN-14 08:43:19.0</td>                    
                    <td>START</td>                    
                    <td>LR 8986</td>                    
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

Here is the working example as per your html, hope it helps. Let me know if any help needed

Comment: Finally it worked. I was missing the style for table.tableView tfoot .links li { display: inline-block; }. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Bootstrap pagination classes - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can align elements in the same line with more than one way, what i like to do is to use css flex properties to manage space between items.

so here is my solutions using css flex properties:

```css
.records {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .records a {
      margin: 14px;
      background-color: red;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="records">
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>3</a>
        <a>4</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: This just reproduces the old result for me.

Comment: could you post for me your html structure under the tbody tag so we could debug it.

Comment: please check the question. Updated the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the image it seems you've list items in your pagination links and you can write a style for it.

so basically you've something like this

```
<ul>
    <li>1<li>
    <li>2<li>
    <li>3<li>
</ul>
```

style would be

```
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You've updated the code now so always show what the html is the next time to get better help.